# Who are the notable bloggers in the Arduino community, and how can we get them involved?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We have established a repository having some excellent questions. Its now time to get the word out about Arduino. There are many people in the online world who manage very active and productive blogs. These individuals have a lot of referral power. They can help us reach new audiences and gain more members for our community.

If you're a blogger, or if you know a blogger, who may be interested in picking one of our most interesting questions, blogging about the topic, and then referring the readers to our site, please mention them below.

Also, share any ideas you may have about how to get them interested in the site (if they aren't already!)

Comment: Did anyone contact Massimo Banzi about promoting arduino.SE or even participating to it? There's no better referrene than he, I think.

Comment: @jfpoilpret Maybe, we should try to get the attention of the people running Arduino.cc and other related blogs before we go directly to the founding team. It makes sense to bring good content to the table when you bring it to the attention of the main Arduino team.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way:

[**Helping the Experts Get Answers**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/helping-the-experts-get-answers/)

> In [A Recipe to Promote your Site](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/), Robert provided a great set of guidelines for organically growing your Q&A community. Buried within was this observation:
>
> > *Reach the right kind of publications and bloggers. Make sure that the key experts in every field know about the site; not just the “Martha Stewart” big names; we want to talk to the people who go to these conferences.*
>
> **But how do you reach writers, bloggers,** and other notable experts in the field?
>
> ### Help them get answers to *their* questions, too!

When a blogger or other publisher/expert has a problem, say to yourself, *"hey, there’s a site for that!"* — then go ahead and **ask the the question on their behalf…** and send them what you find.

If you continue to provide excellent answer like you have been, you have a pretty good chance of adding a valuable member and evangelist to *this* community for a long time to come.

Comment: I wonder if anyone here follows [Arduino on Twitter](https://twitter.com/arduino). This might be a good way to promote our site. Unfortunately, I don't have a Twitter account and haven't bothered creating one.

Comment: I use Twitter occasionally. I tweeted about this site just now, and tagged the official Arduino feed in it. Hopefully it'll get re-tweeted and word will spread. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's Jeremy blum, [JeremyBlum.com](http://www.jeremyblum.com/), I'm an arduino newbie, I searched on Youtube for tutorials, and his videos are **HUGELY** popular. This his [channel](http://www.youtube.com/user/sciguy14)

He seems to be a member on [element14.com](http://www.element14.com/), there seems to be a good experienced arduino community there, I don't know for sure, I'm not a member there.

I don't know how to contact them, try using the contact form on Jeremy's site and introduce this site. I am not qualified to contact him on behalf of this site, I'm not a mod, I just signed, and I am a newbie when it comes to Arduino.

By the way, on arduino.cc forums, there are some very good people, if you can get them to visit this site.

I wish you guys the best of luck, I really was angry when the arduino site went down the first time. I really love arduino, I hope you guys can get the best of the best in the Arduino community. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

### There doesn't seem to be a "respected" Arduino individual that I know of*

*There are a few blogs with a lot of respect but are managed by multiple people. If there was one, single respected person, he/she would probably be posted here already.

- ***[Hack a Day](http://hackaday.com/):*** They post about many fun and creative projects, from automatic flame throwing pumpkins, to DIY heat cameras. I don't know if this is the thing that they would blog about... it's more of a "hard core EE" site. Some beginners that know a lot in other areas but not in Arduino might come here if anything's posted. Also, we might be able to gain some more advanced users and/or questions. EDIT: [We were mentioned on this blog!](http://hackaday.com/2014/03/09/ask-hackaday-wiping-your-bum-with-an-arduino/)
- ***[MAKE](http://makezine.com):*** They post a lot of beginner oriented projects and tutorials. They also have a [store](http://www.makershed.com/?gclid=CMam6N-d9bwCFeY-MgodeQgAUQ) and a magazine. Again, they wouldn't probably won't just put a link in.
- ***[Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com):*** They post mainly tips for the geeky person. If you don't read it, I would recommend it. This one would be hardest to get a link only: but I have an idea to get it on one of this sites...

---

### *How* do we get a link on a site that big?

**We don't, really.** We need to generate great content of how to do something, find a clever solution, and send it in to one of those. For *Hack a Day*, the *[toilet paper question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/564/design-question-how-to-alarm-when-toilet-paper-is-low)* might get mentioned if it generates a great answer. *Make* probably would need a good tutorial on how to do something that they could rewrite with pictures (and throw in a link). *Lifehacker?*: Anything that would make your life more productive and is fairly easy to [DIY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_it_yourself), even for a software kind-of-guy.

---

### I doubt that we could get a mention on all of the sites above.

You wanted a list of "prominent" blogs in the community, I gave you what are read often. (Making it a wiki: edit this list if you want to.) But I think if we work hard, we can get *something* on a popular site.

### *But wait... there's more!*

One thing often overlooked is *[Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/)*. Seriously. Sometimes, Wikipedia comes before the actual site in Google. We currently <strike>aren't</strike> ranked on Google. If someone was Googling something along the lines of, *arduino forum site***, Wikipedia may come up on the first page due to its high [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization). I think we should try all of the above sites, but Wikipedia doesn't *need* any real approval to be posted about. It has great SEO, and we might even get up into Google sooner than without (with cross-linking sites). Note: I'm no expert at SEO, so correct me if I'm wrong anybody.

**Although I hate this, we should probably put some mention about being a forum in the Wikipedia article. It'll get better ranking in Google. We could probably even do:

> Arduino Stack Exchange is similar to a forum, but it is categorized as a [Question and answer site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_question-and-answer_websites). Foo bar blah blah...

Comment: Are there *any* SE sites other than the trilogy([so], [su], [sf]) that have Wikipedia posts?

Comment: @AsheeR Yes, [Ask Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ask_Ubuntu). I'm surprised the pages aren't better maintained... or at least for all sites out of beta. Even the main Stack Exchange page is pretty dull.

Comment: @Annonomus Person: regarding "form" in "Arduino form site", "being a form in", and "similar to a form": Do you mean "forum"?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yep.

Comment: For what its worth, I added a link on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino a few day ago and its still standing. (It took me a few days to build up enough points to comment here)

Answer (score 0):

I don' know if **Nick Gammon** is a "notable blogger", but I've just discovered [his blog](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/index.php?bbtopic_id=123) (actually it seems to be a forum but posts in it are more akin to blog posts) yesterday and found it full of interesting stuff about Arduino, in particular the [interrupts post](http://gammon.com.au/interrupts) which is what brought me there, I found this post incredibly complete about all one would want to know about Arduino interrupts.

He also has a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/nickgammon/arduino_sketches) with a few interesting utilities for Arduino.