# Does anyone know anybody on the Arduino Blog?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We've already looked at *[Who are the notable bloggers in the Arduino community, and how can we get them involved?](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114/who-are-the-notable-bloggers-in-the-arduino-community-and-how-can-we-get-them-i)*. One blog not mentioned was the [Arduino Blog](http://blog.arduino.cc) itself, which is a big influence in the community. If we could get a link on the blog, we could get a lot of traffic and new members  because the blog is read by many people.

Do you know (or are) a blogger on the Arduino blog? Do you have a friend who knows the bloggers of the Arduino blog?

A mention on the Arduino blog would go a long way in taking this site forward.

Comment: [Zoe Romano](https://twitter.com/zoescope) seems to be the main author on the blog.